# AlertDialog.Builder - separation to another class

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Because I often use the AlertDialog I would like seperate it to another class.
I create method:

```
public static void showMessageDialog(Context context, int title, int message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listenerPositive, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listenerNegative) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    if (title > 0) {
        builder.setTitle(title);
    }
    if (messge > 0) {
        builder.setMessage(messge);
    }
    if (listenerPositive != null) {
        builder.setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.button_ok), listenerPositive);
    }
    if (listenerNegative != null) {
        builder.setNegativeButton(context.getString(R.string.button_cancel), listenerNegative);
    }
    AlertDialog ad = builder.create();
    ad.show();
}
```

It's a good practise?

Comment: simply....sure...If You don´t want to do some further stuff inside the dialog, then this will save some work...

Comment: Yes why not. Code optimization is good.

Comment: I asked You because I don't know is the best solution of this method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good solution,I suggest you'd better place it in `BaseActivity`,which abstracts your method will be common used in activity,and let your other activity extends this BaseActivity.

Comment: Thanks, but I think it's too late to create BaseActivity in my project.

Comment: Placing it to a utility class will also be suitable.

Comment: Yes,you can do like this,I mean if you have other util methods for activity or fragment ,you can organize these(including this method) to a simple class.It will reduce your number of classes.

Comment: I woudl like to change my method to `showMessageDialog(Context context, int title, int message, int button_ok, int button_cancel, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listenerPositive, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listenerNegative) ` and create another method for special action example: `showMessageDialogPhoto(Context context, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listenerPositive, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listenerNegative) {
 showMessageDialogcontext, R.string.photo_title, R.string.photo_message, R.string.button_photo_ok, R.string.button_photo_cancel, listenerPositive, listenerNegative)
}`